# Is $\sup_{x : \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j^2 a_j \leq 1} \frac{\sum_j |x_j|}{\sqrt{\sum_j |x_j|^2}} < \infty$?

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Let $X = \{x : \sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j^2 a_j \leq 1\}$, where $a_j$ is a positive, increasing sequence satisfying $\sum_{j} \frac{1}{a_j} < \infty$ and so $a_j \to \infty$.

I am wondering if it is true that
$$
\sup_{x \in X} \frac{\sum_j |x_j|}{\sqrt{\sum_j |x_j|^2}} < \infty.
$$

Cauchy-Schwarz does not seem to help me here, since
although we have $\sum_j |x_j| \leq \sqrt{\sum_{j} |x_j|^2 a_j} \sqrt{\sum_j \frac{1}{a_j}}$,
by taking $x = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a_j}}\right) e_j$ we also have
$$
\sup_{x \in X} \frac{\sqrt{\sum_{j} |x_j|^2 a_j}} { \sqrt{\sum_j |x_j|^2}} 
\geq \sup_j a_j = \infty.
$$

Perhaps there is a more clever way to use Cauchy-Schwarz, or perhaps one can construct a sequence of vectors for which the ratio truly diverges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will prove that
$$
\sup_{x\in X} \frac{\sum_j |x_j|}{\sqrt{\sum_j |x_j|^2}} = +\infty.
$$

Denote $A_N = \sum_{j=1}^N a_j$, and let $x_N = \frac{1}{\sqrt{A_N}}(e_1 + \cdots + e_N)$. Then for each $N$,
$$
\sum_j x^2_{N,j}a_j = 1,
$$
so that $x_N \in X$. Furthermore,

$$
\frac{\sum_j |x_{N,j}|}{\sqrt{\sum_j |x_{N,j}|^2}}=\frac{N}{\sqrt{N}} =\sqrt{N} \to +\infty
$$
as $N \to \infty$.